# How to add an attachment to Testrail using the Testrail API

Tags: api, automation, postman, testrail

I have tried the following API endpoint to add an attachment to Testrail via their API.
But it is not very clear how to name the said file attachment (I am using Postman)

API endpoint:

[POST]
https:///{{testrail link}}/index.php?/api/v2/add_attachment_to_result/449

Headers:
{
"Content-Type","value":"multipart/form-data"
}

What must the body params be?

I have currently selected the file and multipart/form-data for Content-type. Please help!

The error right now on Postman :
{
"error": "No file attached or upload size was exceeded."
}

The upload size is just fine (under 256 MB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using postman you need to pass the file through the body by adding a file type key named 'attachment' and value:{select your file}

eg:
key: attachment | value:myfile.txt

Comment: Thanks -- called the key 'attachment' ; that worked. I would think TR would have that documented somewhere.

Comment: @saniadsouza Can you please help me? I am still getting same error. PFA screenshot

Comment: @MeghaDalvi You still seeing this error? One of the steps I took was to point the image to the right working directory in Postman. Have you done that ? Check this out: https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/settings/#working-directory

Comment: headers as  "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" body as  {
"attachment":"C:\\Users\\20722\\Pictures\\X-SecurityToken-Issue.jpg"
}  but still getting failure.. can u confirm that this is correct?

Comment: @saniadsouza: headers as "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" body as { "attachment":"C:\\Users\\20722\\Pictures\\X-SecurityToken-Issue.jpg" } but still getting failure.. can u confirm that this is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Java example - I know it's a little late, but it may be useful for reference:

```
public void uploadScreenshot(long resultId, String screenshotFile) {

    String url = String.format("add_attachment_to_result/%d", resultId);

    try {
        client.sendPost(url, screenshot);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can add an attachment to various assets within TestRail, in this example I am adding a screenshot to a result, which has to be passed in (when you add a result you can get the JSON response and store the 'id' of the newly created result.